# Java: наследование контркуктора

Tags: java, наследование

Объясните дураку(в основном работаю с php), почему при наследовании исключений, не наследуются все конструкторы.

***Кейс №1***
Есть класс расширяющий исключения(без конструктора)

```
package test.exceptions;
public class StatusException extends Exception {
    final public static String STATUS_NOT_EXIST = "Status: not exist";
}
```

Есть код выкидывающий исключение:

```
public static void test() throws StatusException {
    String message= StatusException.STATUS_NOT_EXIST;
    throw new StatusException(message);
}
```

При компиляции получаю ошибку о несоответствие сигнатур конструкторов

```
Error:(26, 15) java: constructor StatusException in class test.exceptions.StatusException cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: java.lang.String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

***Кейс №2***
Исключение с конструктором принимающим String

```
package test.exceptions;
public class StatusException extends Exception {
    final public static String STATUS_NOT_EXIST = "Status: not exist";

    public StatusException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Код выкидывающий исключение:

```
public static void test() throws StatusException {
    String message= StatusException.STATUS_NOT_EXIST;
    throw new StatusException();
}
```

Ошибка

```
Error:(24, 15) java: constructor StatusException in class test.exceptions.StatusException cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Comment: А почему должны-то?

Comment: @Qwertiy А почему не должны?

Comment: Потому что у класса же конструктор что-то ещё делает. Раз не написал, значит не хочешь. Всё логично.

Comment: @Qwertiy ни слова не понял. Или пишите ответ в развёрнутом виде, или не флудите.

Comment: Класс наследует все члены (поля, методы и вложенные классы) своего супер-класса. Конструкторы не члены, поэтому они не наследуются классами, но конструктор супер-класса может быть вызван в классе.Так написано на сайте oracle в учебнике по java http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: @Sergey А не желаете оформить ответ прямо в виде цитаты: "A subclass inherits all the members (fields, methods, and nested classes) from its superclass. Constructors are not members, so they are not inherited by subclasses, but the constructor of the superclass can be invoked from the subclass", - с переводом и ссылочкой? 2 положительных разносторонних ответа - это ведь здорово. P.S. Честно говоря, я сам сразу начал искать упоминание этого в документации `java`, но вы сделали это быстрее меня :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Конструкторы не наследуются. 
Касательно первого примера - вы должны явно создать конструктор с параметром:

```
public class StatusException extends Exception {

    final public static String STATUS_NOT_EXIST = "Status: not exist";

    public StatusException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

Касательно второго примера.
Если явно не задан ни один конструктор, то по умолчанию создается пустой конструктор без параметров. То есть в первом примере у вас будет неявно создан такой конструктор. Если же явно определен хотя бы один конструктор, то конструктор без параметров следует так же явно указать. Следовательно, для второго примера нужно так:

```
public class StatusException extends Exception {
    final public static String STATUS_NOT_EXIST = "Status: not exist";

    public StatusException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public StatusException() {
        //nothing or call super
    }
}
```

Comment: ++ Я бы еще также упомянул тот факт, что в конструкторе без параметров наследника автоматически вызовется конструктор без параметров родителя, т.е. `super()`, т.е. как раз тот, что нужен в данном случае (именно поэтому его вызов писать необязательно).